# angularjs $http: server 500 (Internal Server Error) when working with laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4, filter, ionic-framework

I have searched many solutions but still cannot work.
it shows me

```
POST http://localhost/travelAbroad/public/touristsData 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

what i wanna do is that when i choose the filters, the   will change according to the filters you choose. And i use ionic as a frontend framework to make a html5 mobile application.

The following is my code:

//html

```
    <span class="ion-ios-arrow-down button button-icon" ng-click="modal.show()"></span>  
...
   <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="tourist in tourists | limitTo:numberOfItemsToDisplay">
             <h3>Charge: $@{{tourist.charge}}/h</h3>
          </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

//filterModal  file

```
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-content>
     <form name="filterForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
      <div class="list">
          <ion-radio ng-model="filter.want" value="company" name="want">
            Want a company for building a house
          </ion-radio>
          <ion-radio ng-model="filter.want" value="expat" name="want">
            Find an expaters
          </ion-radio>

          <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
              <select ng-model="filter.location" name="location">
                <option value="Xihu" selected>Xihu</option>
                <option value="Xiacheng">Xiacheng</option>
              </select>
            </label>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" ng-model="filter.token" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="submit" class="button button-full button-light" value="Create">
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
```

//angular controller

```
.controller('listController', ['$scope','$http','$state','$ionicModal', function($scope, $http, $state,$ionicModal){

$http.get("./touristsData").success(
     function(data){
        $scope.tourists = data;
        $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay = 3; // number of item to load each time
        $scope.addMoreItems = function(){
          if($scope.tourists.length>$scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay){
            $scope.numberOfItemsToDisplay += 3; // load 20 more items

          }
       ............

});//end of get method

$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('./filterModal', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.filter = {};
  $scope.submitForm = function(){
    if($scope.filter.want == 'company'){
          $http({
              method  : 'POST',
              url     : './touristsData',
              beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                          var token = $scope.filter.token;
                          if (token) {
                            return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                          }
              },                  
              data    : {
                  location: $scope.filter.location
              },
              headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
          })
          .success(function(data){
               $scope.tourists = data;
          });    
          $scope.modal.hide();                   
    }
  }
```

//backend
//laravel route:

```
  Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/touristsData', array(
    'uses' => 'UserController@touristsData',
    'as' => 'touristsData'
  ));
```

//laravel controller:

```
   public function touristsData(){//get

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

   //$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

   if(isset($request->location)){
           @$location = $request->location;
           $tourists = User::where('block','0')
                       ->where('location', $location)
                       ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                       ->get();                

     }else{
          $tourists = User::where('block','0')
                      ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                      ->get();      
     }
    //$touristsPostInfo = Post::where('block','0')->get();  

   return View::make('frontend.data.touristsData',array('tourists'=>$tourists));

   }
```

//touristsData

```
  echo json_encode($tourists);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel with ionic :500 (Internal Server Error)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131884/laravel-with-ionic-500-internal-server-error)

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your header:

```
<meta id="token" name="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: I put it and changed "var token = $scope.filter.token;"  to ''var token = document.getElementById('#token').getAttribute('content');''  in my submitForm function. But still didn't work. Did i miss something?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error is captured on the **error log file of your server**,
you can login with FTP and get the **error.log** file to check **exactly** the line and what is the problem.

```
$http: server 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: sorry,i use local environment and laravel framework. the errors in the laravel.log did not show very detailed info.

Comment: Apache server(if you use apache) creates and updates the error.log each time it crashes something on PHP files, so it is independent from local and from framework, i keep use it for my PHP errors. 
Anyway no problem , Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're server is expecting a url encoded string and you are sending through an object thus it throws the error.

Update following

```
data:  {
    location: $scope.filter.location
}
```

To

```
data    : $httpParamSerializer({
    location: $scope.filter.location
})
```

You'll need to inject the `$httpParamSerializer` function.